# GitHub: Skipping Workflow on Issues Update via API

Tags: github, github-actions, octokit, octokit-js

Maybe this is out of the box, maybe not. But I can't find this in any of the documentation.

I know you can skip workflows on Push and Pull_Requests. However, I need to skip workflows when updating Issues via the REST API.

My current workflow yaml looks like the following:

```yaml
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '10/15 * * * *'
  issues:
    types: [opened, closed, deleted, reopened, edited, labeled, unlabeled, assigned, unassigned]
  issue_comment:
    types: [created]
```

The `schedule` job does some clean-up on issues via a custom action that leverages the GitHub/Octokit REST API.

Is there a way that I can prevent the workflow from running if the issue is updated via the API?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, [you can only skip workflow runs triggered by the `push` and `pull_request` events](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/skipping-workflow-runs). In your case (with ISSUE), you would need to add a check in a job or expression to identify if you should run or not the workflows operations.

Answer (score 1):

As @GuiFalourd points out in the comments, I think you will need to use [Workflow Expressions](https://As%20@GuiFalourd%20points,%20I%20think%20you%20will%20need%20to%20use%20https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#example-matching-an-array-of-strings). To differentiate between a GitHub API call or a user interaction call I'm not sure if there is an official way to do so, I would open an issue in [GitHub Community](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/). I'm sure they will help you with that.

A couple of workarounds coming to my mind is to use a special 'Issue label' to mark when the GitHub API is used, this way you can filter accordingly (not a fan of this solution).

Also, if you are using a certain GitHub user to do API requests, you can use `github.actor` and `github.triggering_actor` from [GitHub context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) to identify which user is triggering the event.

Here's a draft on how my approach would look like:

```yaml
steps:
  - uses: actions/hello-world-javascript-action@v1.1
    if: ${{ contains(fromJson('["push", "pull_request"]'), github.event_name) && github.actor == <your_actor_name> }}
```